# JVM Error 525 : Bad persistent object

Tags: blackberry, hashtable, persistent, jvm-crash

I'm trying to add a string value and a customized horizontal field manager to a HashTable. String being the key and the custom horizontal field manager being the value. I do remove the pair from the Hashtable whenever the horizontal field managers are removed from the screen. Also, I'm not persisting the Hashtable.

I get the error JVM Error 525 : Bad persistent object after a few minutes on the simulator. When I try to run the same build on a device it restarts after a few minutes of creation of the Hashtable. Please note that everything works fine if I just don't push anything in the Hashtable.

So my question is, is it wrong to put a Horizontal Field Manager or something extended from it in a HashTable? If not, what could be the problem here?

Comment: You mentioned you're not persisting the hashtable, are you not persisting it *at all*, or just not calling commit when the manager is stored in it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all of the objects being persisted (including those added to the HashTable) implement the Persistable interface.